# How to merge insert a column from a temp table and parameters from stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, sql-merge

is this the "right" way to do that?

```
merge dbo.tableA as tgt
using (select #temptable.pkid, @spParam1 as col1, @spParam2 as col2 from #temptable)
as src
on tgt.pkid = src.pkid
when not matched by target when
   insert (pkid, thing1, thing2) values (src.pkid, col1, col2)
;
```

Is there a different or better way?

Comment: if you hv to insert/update/delete something more then you have to explain that .
you should have purpose of using merge like you need output or there are more than one dml.

Answer (score 1):

without using merge this sql will work for you.

```
insert into dbo.tableA (pkid, thing1, thing2)
   select #temptable.pkid, @spParam1 as col1, @spParam2 as col2 from #temptable src
   left join dbo.tableA as tgt on tgt.pkid = src.pkid
```